# Must HEAD point to a branch?

Tags: git

Must HEAD point to a branch, or can it point directly to a commit node? Is it possible to move HEAD to point to an arbitrary commit node even if no branch is referencing this node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Must HEAD point to a branch, or can it point directly to a commit?

HEAD is just a pointer to a commit. It is possible that no branch points to that commit.

> Is it possible to move HEAD to point to an arbitrary commit even if no branch is referencing this commit?

Yes, it is.
Just do:

```
git checkout <commit-sha>
```

and you will check out that commit in a *detached head* state. That basically means that you are currently not on a branch.

Comment: Thanks. Can I substitute  a SHA1 of a commit  for `<refspec>`?

Comment: Is it possible, then, to delete all branches from a repository, including `master`, and work solely with `HEAD`?

Comment: I just tried it now and yes, it is possible. Now when I do `git branch -a` I only get `* (HEAD detached from ebe50df)` listed as a branch.

Comment: But HEAD cannot be deleted, right? Even if there is one or more other branches in the repository.

Comment: I don't see how that would be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Read this full answer:

[How to move HEAD back to a previous location? (Detached head)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-back-to-a-previous-location-detached-head/34519716#34519716)

HEAD can be point to any commit, If HEAD is **not pointing** to a the latest commit in the branch you are in a **detached HEAD**.

Read the above answer to get the full detailed what is it and how to "fix" it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. When you clone or initialize a repository, is it possible to specify that it be created without any branch references, not even `master`, except for HEAD?

Comment: nope but you can thsn detach any branch and delete all your history

Comment: Thanks. And, unlike branches, HEAD cannot be renamed, correct?

Comment: HEAD is simply a pointer to commit you cant rename since its not a real branch